# Make ViewPager swipable through external layout / from outside

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager

In my application I have an activity thats layout  is basicly following:

[App layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVVcg.png)

The red part is a viewpager with fragments.
The blue part is a layout with buttons that doesnt change with swipe on viewpager.
But i want that the viewpager is swipable (smoothly) in the hole green framed area. It should act like normal viewpager behavior.

I have absolutely no idea if that is even possible or not, but hope it does.

I thought that it is maybe possible with a gestureoverlay or something, but don't know how to apply the detected gesture on the viewpager.
Only detecting swipe and set current page is not what I want achieve.

(I'm writing in java)

Comment: Do you want it like this? The Red part is your viewpager and the blue is your button view.  Check the link given below

https://imgur.com/rpdxfUI

Comment: @Maitri basicly, but the blue part should recognice and handle swipes for the viewpager too.

Comment: yes that can be managed from your java/kotlin class

Comment: @Maitri I thought that, but the question is how? Which Methods do I have to override? (Java)

Comment: @ Blood_Working_  content of viewpager is static or dynamic?

Comment: @Maitri viewpager contains (dynamic) fragments. But always the same amount of fragments (3).

Comment: Then no need to override any method.. you can do it by set currentItem

Answer (score 0):

If the height of the viewpager and buttons layout are somewhat fixed, here is a solution:

1, use a ConstraintLayout as the root container

2, make viewpager the same size as the root, set the viewpager's padding to some value say 8dp

3, place the buttons layout over the view pager, taking up the bottom half space(except for some margin), the viewpager should still respond to touch where there is no button

4, for fragments inside view pager, use a ConstraintLayout to put the content at the top half of the page

Comment: The problem is that the "blue" part  is a layout with own background, that i am including. So the viewpager doesnt repond to touch/swipe from it

Comment: it does. unless your background has its own touch/click handler, in which case the swipe/scroll shouldn't happen anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for 
[Nested Action Bar Tabs(with ViewPager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262232/nested-action-bar-tabswith-viewpager/40450558#40450558)

There's also a demo on Github: https://github.com/r3dm4n/NestedActionBarTabswithViewPagerDEMO
Let me know if it helped

Comment: Sry, but that is absolutely not what I am looking for. But still thanks for answering!