# ViewPager inside Viewpager (Non swipeable )

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have 2  views in the outer view pager. I want to change these views only with some button click.

```
 setcurrentItem();
```

So now I have another inner view pager which I want to it be swipe able. but when I make outer view pager's touch event as false nor does the inner view pager work. How do i proceed?
give me suggestions.

Comment: "i make outer view pager's touch event as false" explain that mystery

Comment: @pskink thanks, i tried as you said but inner view pager doesn't swipe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098868/viewpager-inside-viewpager

Comment: @keshav i have seen that answer but it is not working

Comment: what u tried from there? See last second answer .

Comment: @keshav  its not for my question i want inner pager swipe able and outer pager fixed.