# Call Activity which extends FragmentActivity using Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have Activity for `tabLayout` using `ViewPager`.
**Code :**

```
public class Home extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private String[] tabs = { "Instant Opportunity", "Events", "Experts" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

}
**And another activity for Slider, code is as below :**

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new Home();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Gallery();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Now, here at case 0: I want to call that Home activity. But It is showing error. How to call this ?

When I take cursor on new Home(), It says can't convert from Home to Fragment.

Comment: what error you got? post it.

Comment: `Home` must to be a Fragment and not an Activity. You **cannot** put an Activity as an item inside a ViewPager! Make sure that `Home` is a Fragment.

Comment: Go to this [http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/)

Comment: The error appears because indeed `Home` is not a Fragment. As I understand, `Home` is a Fragment which have an Inner ViewPager, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but how to prevent this problem ? I want to show ViewPager in home activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ViewPager` inside a `Fragment`. You have to use *inner fragments* with the [nested fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) method, as you can read on the Documentation:

> **You can now embed fragments inside fragments.** This is useful for a variety of situations in which you want to place dynamic and re-usable UI components into a UI component that is itself dynamic and re-usable. **For example, if you use ViewPager to create fragments that swipe left and right and consume a majority of the screen space, you can now insert fragments into each fragment page.**

You need to change `Home` as `extends Fragment` and use [`getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) method for your adapter. There are some revelant posts on this kind of behaviour:

- [ViewPager inside ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098868/viewpager-inside-viewpager)
- [How set ViewPager inside a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073541/how-set-viewpager-inside-a-fragment)
- [Display fragment viewpager within a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700226/display-fragment-viewpager-within-a-fragment)
- [How to add a Fragment inside a ViewPager using Nested Fragment (Android 4.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391359/2668136)

Hope this helps.