# Scrollinghorizontal in viewpage, action bar

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have done my android with viewpage and actionbar. It perfectly work but now i am wanting to my viewpage have horizontal scrolling now.
If we disable the swiping. Can i swipe with horizontal scrollview in my fragment.
. Please help!! thank you very much

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    ActionBar actionbar;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    FragmentPageAdapter ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        actionbar = getActionBar();
        viewpager.setAdapter(ft);
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Heroes").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Items").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Mechanics").setTabListener(this));


        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help you.

I have a similar situation, where I have to use Viewpager in Viewpager, I searched and found a solution, here is that solution

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668216/3884250) and it works on gallery too... And gallery is sort of horizontal scroll.

Comment: hmm i researched that answer but my class using Fragment not Viewpager. Do you know how to code it not using the method.