# Swiping fragments in fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, swipe, gesture

Can anyone tell me, how to make a tab viewer with fragments? Something like in image:

[image]

`Activity`, which contains two fragments, one of the fragments contains tabs with two fragments.

Comment: what have you tried?  this is no different then having the tabs directly in your activity.  heres a pretty basic tab example http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098868/viewpager-inside-viewpager

Comment: + for cool mockup ;)