# ViewPager+Fragment+SeekBar, page changing with seekbar dragging

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, seekbar

I added 2 Fragment pages into a ViewPager, one of them contains a SeekBar to controll music playing. Just like the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it5o4.png)
The question is when I drag the thumb, the page changes, which is not I want. 
How can I solve that?
Thank you very much.:)

Comment: I silved it with this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/13668216/6468790

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ViewPager inside ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098868/viewpager-inside-viewpager)